# Prometheus Grafana - duplicate metrics returned

Tags: prometheus, grafana

Whenever I'm querying metrics, I am getting duplicate results - two versions of the same metric.

Thq query: `{exported_job="@abc/mailer", job="otel-collector"}`

The two duplicate results I'm getting:

```
{__name__="messages_processed_nacked_total", exported_job="@abc/mailer", instance="otel-collector:9464", job="otel-collector"}
```

and then one more time:

```
messages_processed_nacked_total {__name__="messages_processed_nacked_total", exported_job="@abc/mailer", instance="otel-collector:9464", job="otel-collector"}
```

Which is resulting to having duplicate entries on any visualisations in Grafana.

Is this something basic I'm missing?

---

EDIT/UPDATE: After checking Prometheus on 9090, there is no duplicate there, which surely means it's something with Grafana. Having that said, here's the Grafana datasource provisioning yaml:

```
# config file version
apiVersion: 1

# list of datasources that should be deleted from the database
deleteDatasources:
    - name: Prometheus
      orgId: 1

# list of datasources to insert/update depending
# whats available in the database
datasources:
    # <string, required> name of the datasource. Required
    - name: Prometheus
      # <string, required> datasource type. Required
      type: prometheus
      # uid needed for Tempo
      uid: prometheus
      # <string, required> access mode. direct or proxy. Required
      access: proxy
      # <int> org id. will default to orgId 1 if not specified
      orgId: 1
      # <string> url
      url: http://prometheus:9090
      # <string> database password, if used
      password:
      # <string> database user, if used
      user:
      # <string> database name, if used
      database:
      # <bool> enable/disable basic auth
      basicAuth: false
      # <string> basic auth username, if used
      basicAuthUser:
      # <string> basic auth password, if used
      basicAuthPassword:
      # <bool> enable/disable with credentials headers
      withCredentials:
      # <bool> mark as default datasource. Max one per org
      isDefault: true
      # <map> fields that will be converted to json and stored in json_data
      jsonData:
          graphiteVersion: '1.1'
          tlsAuth: false
          tlsAuthWithCACert: false
      # <string> json object of data that will be encrypted.
      secureJsonData:
          tlsCACert: '...'
          tlsClientCert: '...'
          tlsClientKey: '...'
      version: 1
      # <bool> allow users to edit datasources from the UI.
      editable: true
    - name: Loki
      type: loki
      uid: loki
      access: proxy
      url: http://loki:3100
      #   basicAuth: true
      #   basicAuthUser: my_user
      jsonData:
          maxLines: 1000
          derivedFields:
              # Field with internal link pointing to data source in Grafana.
              # datasourceUid value can be anything, but it should be unique across all defined data source uids.
              - datasourceUid: tempo
                matcherRegex: "\"trace_id\":\\s*\"([a-f0-9]+)\""

                name:
                    TraceID
                    # url will be interpreted as query for the datasource
                url:
                    '$${__value.raw}'
                    # optional for URL Label to set a custom display label for the link.
                urlDisplayLabel:
                    'View Trace'

                    # Field with external link.
              # - matcherRegex: "traceID=(\\w+)"
              #   name: TraceID
              #   url: 'http://localhost:16686/trace/$${__value.raw}'
              - datasourceUid: tempo
                matcherRegex: "\"span_id\":\\s*\"([a-f0-9]+)\""
                name: SpanID
              # secureJsonData:
              # basicAuthPassword: test_password
    - name: Tempo
      type: tempo
      access: proxy
      orgId: 1
      url: http://tempo:3200
      basicAuth: false
      isDefault: false
      version: 1
      editable: false
      apiVersion: 1
      uid: tempo
      jsonData:
          httpMethod: GET
          tracesToLogsV2:
              # Field with an internal link pointing to a logs data source in Grafana.
              # datasourceUid value must match the uid value of the logs data source.
              datasourceUid: 'loki'
              spanStartTimeShift: '1h'
              spanEndTimeShift: '-1h'
              tags: [{ 'key': 'service.name', value: 'serviceName' }]
              filterByTraceID: true
              filterBySpanID: true
              customQuery: true
              query: '{$${__tags}} | json | trace_id ="$${__trace.traceId}" or span_id ="$${__span.spanId}"'
          lokiSearch:
              datasourceUid: 'loki'
          tracesToMetrics:
              datasourceUid: 'prometheus'
              spanStartTimeShift: '1h'
              spanEndTimeShift: '-1h'
              tags: [{ key: 'service.name', value: 'service' }, { key: 'job' }]
              queries:
                  - name: 'Sample query'
                    query: 'sum(rate(traces_spanmetrics_latency_bucket{$$__tags}[5m]))'
          nodeGraph:
              enabled: true
          search:
              hide: false
          traceQuery:
              timeShiftEnabled: true
              spanStartTimeShift: '1h'
              spanEndTimeShift: '-1h'
          spanBar:
              type: 'Tag'
              tag: 'http.path'
          serviceMap:
              datasourceUid: prometheus
```

Thanks

Comment: Your query looks fine. Can you show how duplication looks? Also, is the same duplication present when querying Prometheus directly, not from Grafana?

Comment: Hi, those are actually the results. I've modified my question to include the query I'm using

Comment: Never seems anything like this. Check if results are the same when querying prometheus directly, and if yes - consider opening an issue in their [prometheus] repo.

Comment: Update: I've checked Prometheus on :9090, and I can see the entry just once, it must be a Grafana thing.

Comment: Check query and results: in the menu of panel Inspect. Look both at shown query and data (select some small time range beforehand to lower number of data points). Also, if you don't see duplication there - check you transformations.